# How to drawImage(); repeatedly onto canvas using "mousemove"

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, window

I'm running into a roadblock with my code. I need to be able to draw random sized images (of whatever) onto the canvas on "mousemove".

This is some example code from my teacher that I've cherry picked together in order to get the circles to appear randomly, but I don't want circles, I want an image with an src.

I feel like this should be an easy tweak?

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"), context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var circleSize = 200;

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", drawPumpkin);


function drawPumpkin(e){

    var loc = windowToCanvas(canvas, e.clientX, e.clientY);


    console.log("Mouse location: "+loc.y);
    context.beginPath();

    context.arc(loc.x,loc.y,randRange(5,40),0,Math.PI*2,false);

    context.fill();
    context.stroke();

    }
```

Here is the .html:

```
<DOCTYPE!>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Pumpkin Emulator!</title>

        <style>
            body {
                background: #858585;
            }
            #canvas {
                margin: 10px;
                padding: 10px;
                background: #c5eaf0;
                border: thin inset #aaaaaa;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="300">
        Canvas not supported
        </canvas>

        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>    


    function windowToCanvas(canvas, x, y){

        var bbox = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        return {x: x - bbox.left * (canvas.width/bbox.width),
                y: y - bbox.top * (canvas.height/bbox.height)
               }
        }


    function randRange (min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }
```

Comment: Hmmm...this basic info should be in your textbook -- did you look? ;-) You can draw an image object onto the canvas in various sizes with the `drawImage(imageObject,x,y,width,height)` command. The image source can be: an image object, another canvas, a video element.

Comment: I did spend quite some time reading over reference tables trying to piece together everything, and another hour or so on w3schools, but w3schools only offers examples with populating img's in a <p>, and only once haha. I had no idea where to go for a canvas example, and google can sometimes be a bottomless pit...

Comment: Instructive link: http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001654/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Easy

To create an image

```
var myImage = new Image();   // creates an image element
myImage.src = "myimage.png"; // set image.src to the URL pointing to the image
// the image will now load and we will assume that there are no errors finding and loading the image. ie wrong / malformed URL.
```

Now replace the drawPumpkin function with

```
function drawImage(e){
    var loc, imageSize;      // declare the variables you will use
    if(myImage.complete){    // check that the images has finished loading
        // get the location of the mouse on the canvas
        loc = windowToCanvas(canvas, e.clientX, e.clientY); 
        imageSize = randRange(5,40);      // get the size to draw the image
        loc.x -= imageSize/2;             // we want the image to be centered on the mouse
        loc.y -= imageSize/2;             // so offset the image by half the draw size
        // now draw the image
        context.drawImage(myImage,                  // the image to draw
                  0,0,myImage.width,myImage.height, // what part of the image to draw
                                                    // in this case all of the image
                  loc.x,loc.y,imageSize,imageSize   // where and how big it should be on the canvas
        );
    }
}
```

Don't forget to change the event listener to the new function.

And that is it.

Answer (score 0):

jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/CanvasCode/dLoh4fxf/

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

function windowToCanvas(canvas, x, y) {

    var bbox = c.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
        x: x - bbox.left * (canvas.width / bbox.width),
        y: y - bbox.top * (canvas.height / bbox.height)
    }
}


function randRange(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function drawPumpkin(e) {

    var loc = windowToCanvas(c, e.clientX, e.clientY);


    console.log("Mouse location: " + loc.y);
    ctx.beginPath();

    ctx.drawImage(img, loc.x, loc.y);

}

var img = new Image();
img.src = "http://orig09.deviantart.net/314c/f/2011/218/7/2/nyan_cat_sprite_by_pincers1066-d45od59.jpg";

c.addEventListener("mousemove", drawPumpkin);
ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,c.width,c.height);
```

All you need to do is simply load an image and then just draw that using the `context.drawImage`.